# ReactJS Custom Cursor with Dynamic Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-splitting

I have a custom cursor component based off Codrops https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/01/31/custom-cursor-effects/.

I have it working nicely on every page except one, which is a portfolio page that dynamically shows/hides content based on the current state.

If I change states (show component not initially loaded + hide initial component OR hide component not initially loaded + show initially loaded content), the custom cursor no longer reacts to the class name.

I am showing/hiding the content based on the current state of the component.

I've tried to re "init" the cursor, but that causes problems with the size/position of the custom cursor.

I understand the Cursor.js doesn't know when to "look" for the new classes after the state change, but I can't figure out how to make it "watch" for the changes, and since re initializing the cursor isn't working, I'm not sure what I should try. Should I try an eventListener that forces the cursor to look at the classes again?

Ideally the custom cursor will interact with both dynamic and non-dynamic elements, but I'm at a point that I question if this is even possible.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Or if anyone has an example of a React Custom Cursor that works in this scenario, I'd love to check it out.

Portfolio.js

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <div className="cursor">
      <div className="circle-cursor circle-cursor--inner"></div>
    </div>
    <canvas
      className="circle-cursor circle-cursor--outer"
      resize="true"
    ></canvas>
    //CURSOR
    <CustomCursor />
    //SHOW ALL PROJECTS ON STATE CHANGE
    { this.state.showAllItems ? 
    <div className={styles.grid}>
      {list.map(item => (
        <div key={item.index} className={styles.grid__item}>
          <a href="#/a" key={item.index} value={item.index} onClick={e => this.onClick(e, item)} >
            <div key={item.index}  className={styles.glitch + " portfolioLinkHover " + styles.glitchStyle1}>
              <div className={styles.glitch__img + " img"} style={{background: 'url('+ item.imgSrc + ') no-repeat 50% 0'}}></div>
              <div className={styles.glitch__img + " img"} style={{background: 'url('+ item.imgSrc + ') no-repeat 50% 0'}}></div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <h2>{item.itemTitle} <span>{item.itemSubtitle}</span></h2>
            </a>
          </p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
    : null }
    //SHOW PROJECT ON STATE CHANGE
    { this.state.currentProject ? 
      <div className={styles.projectContainer + " portfolioLinkHover"}>
        <Project />
      </div>  : null }
  </div>
);
}
```

Cursor.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Util from "./utils/util";
import './styles/cursor.scss';
import TweenMax from 'gsap';

class CustomCursor extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isOn: this.props.isOn };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    if(this.state.isOn == "true"){
      this.initHovers();
    }
    else{
      this.initCursor();
      this.initCanvas();
      this.initHovers();
    }
  }

  initCursor() {
    this.clientX = -100;
    this.clientY = -100;
    this.innerCursor = document.querySelector(".circle-cursor--inner");
    this.outerCursor = document.querySelector(".custom-cursor--outer");
    this.outerCursorSpeed = 1;
    this.lastX = 0;
    this.lastY = 0;
    this.isStuck = false;
    this.showCursor = false;
    const { paper } = window;

    const unveilCursor = e => {
      this.group.position = new paper.Point(e.clientX, e.clientY);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.outerCursorSpeed = 0.2;
      }, 100);
      this.showCursor = true;
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", unveilCursor);

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
      this.clientX = e.clientX;
      this.clientY = e.clientY;
    });

    const render = () => {
      TweenMax.set(this.innerCursor, {
        x: this.clientX,
        y: this.clientY
      });
      if (this.showCursor) {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", unveilCursor);
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  initCanvas() {
    const { paper, SimplexNoise } = window;
    const canvas = document.querySelector(".circle-cursor--outer");
    const shapeBounds = {
      width: 75,
      height: 75
    };
    paper.setup(canvas);

    const strokeColor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
    const strokeWidth = 1;
    const segments = 8;
    const radius = 25;
    const noiseScale = 150; // speed
    const noiseRange = 4; // range of distortion
    let isNoisy = false;

    const polygon = new paper.Path.RegularPolygon(
      new paper.Point(0, 0),
      segments,
      radius
    );
    polygon.strokeColor = strokeColor;
    polygon.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    polygon.smooth();

    this.group = new paper.Group([polygon]);
    this.group.applyMatrix = false;

    const noiseObjects = polygon.segments.map(() => new SimplexNoise());
    let bigCoordinates = [];

    paper.view.onFrame = event => {
      if (!this.isStuck) {
        // move circle around normally
        this.lastX = Util.lerp(this.lastX, this.clientX, this.outerCursorSpeed);
        this.lastY = Util.lerp(this.lastY, this.clientY, this.outerCursorSpeed);
        this.group.position = new paper.Point(this.lastX, this.lastY);
      } else if (this.isStuck) {
        // fixed position on a nav item
        this.lastX = Util.lerp(this.lastX, this.stuckX, this.outerCursorSpeed);
        this.lastY = Util.lerp(this.lastY, this.stuckY, this.outerCursorSpeed);
        this.group.position = new paper.Point(this.lastX, this.lastY);
      }

      if (this.isStuck && polygon.bounds.width < shapeBounds.width) {
        // scale up the shape
        polygon.scale(1.08);
      } else if (!this.isStuck && polygon.bounds.width > 30) {
        // remove noise
        if (isNoisy) {
          polygon.segments.forEach((segment, i) => {
            segment.point.set(bigCoordinates[i][0], bigCoordinates[i][1]);
          });
          isNoisy = false;
          bigCoordinates = [];
        }

        // scale down the shape
        const scaleDown = 0.92;
        polygon.scale(scaleDown);
      }

      // while stuck and when big, do perlin noise
      if (this.isStuck && polygon.bounds.width >= shapeBounds.width) {
        isNoisy = true;

        // first get coordinates of large circle
        if (bigCoordinates.length === 0) {
          polygon.segments.forEach((segment, i) => {
            bigCoordinates[i] = [segment.point.x, segment.point.y];
          });
        }

        // calculate noise value for each point at that frame
        polygon.segments.forEach((segment, i) => {
          const noiseX = noiseObjects[i].noise2D(event.count / noiseScale, 0);
          const noiseY = noiseObjects[i].noise2D(event.count / noiseScale, 1);

          const distortionX = Util.map(noiseX, -1, 1, -noiseRange, noiseRange);
          const distortionY = Util.map(noiseY, -1, 1, -noiseRange, noiseRange);

          const newX = bigCoordinates[i][0] + distortionX;
          const newY = bigCoordinates[i][1] + distortionY;

          segment.point.set(newX, newY);
        });
      }

      // hover state for main nav items
      if (this.fillOuterCursor && polygon.fillColor !== strokeColor) {
        polygon.fillColor = strokeColor;
        polygon.strokeColor = "transparent";
      } else if (!this.fillOuterCursor && polygon.fillColor !== "transparent") {
        polygon.strokeColor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
        polygon.fillColor = "transparent";
      }

      // hover state for portfolio nav items
      if (this.isOnPortfolioItem) {
        polygon.fillColor = strokeColor;
        polygon.strokeColor = "rgba(255, 226, 0, 0.5)";
        // scale up the shape
        polygon.bounds.width = 45;
        polygon.bounds.height = 45;
      } else if (!this.fillOuterCursor) {
        polygon.strokeColor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
        polygon.fillColor = "transparent";
      }
      polygon.smooth();
    };
  }

  initHovers() {
    const handleMouseEnter = e => {
      const navItem = e.currentTarget;
      const navItemBox = navItem.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.stuckX = Math.round(navItemBox.left + navItemBox.width / 2);
      this.stuckY = Math.round(navItemBox.top + navItemBox.height / 2);
      this.isStuck = true;
    };

    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
      this.isStuck = false;
    };

    const linkItems = document.querySelectorAll(".browser-window__link");
    linkItems.forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener("mouseenter", handleMouseEnter);
      item.addEventListener("mouseleave", handleMouseLeave);
    });

    const mainNavItemMouseEnter = () => {
      this.outerCursorSpeed = 0.8;
      this.fillOuterCursor = true;
    };
    const mainNavItemMouseLeave = () => {
      this.outerCursorSpeed = 0.2;
      this.fillOuterCursor = false;
    };
    const portfolioItems = document.querySelectorAll(".portfolioLinkHover");
    portfolioItems.forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener("mouseenter", handleLinkEnter);
      item.addEventListener("mouseleave", handleLinkLeave);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomCursor;
```

Comment: I didn't understand well, your problem. It seems you don't pass Portfolio state change to CustomCursor so it could make updates.best if you supply a simplyfied codesandbox to examine the issue.

Comment: @gaditzkhori that's right, when I passed the state change I tried to reinit the cursor, but that caused problems, so I didn't know how to update the CustomCursor so it can make updates. calling the init function didn't work, and I wasn't sure what else I should try there.

Comment: So the issue is with the implementation of CustomCursor

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how to make it work with components that aren't present on pageload.

Comment: can you add codesandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: try add `componentDidUpdate` to `CustomCursor` then when state changes you can init your cursor. for best practices please: `this.state.isOn == "true"` should be `this.state.isOn == true` not a string. try use `React.createRef` instead of `querySelector`. put the cursor `canvas` and jsx in `CustomCursor` .

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice @gaditzkhori!! Giving that a go today.